# How do I print an __init__() inside of a function?

Tags: python, function, initialization, python-3.7

Whenever I'm trying to print the code below I get `<__main__.Initial object at 0x106071ee0>`:

```py
# INITILIZATION
class Initial:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5):
        self.definition = arg1
        self.other = arg2
        self.present = arg3
        self.imperfect = arg4
        self.perfect = arg5


# DEFINITIONS

def salve():
    dictator = Initial("hello\n" ,"Salvete = hello (plural)\n" , None , None, None)
    print(dictator)
salve()
```

How do I print desired arguments using standard `print` function?

Comment: Yes it does, but now I can't delete my question since someone else wrote down an answer

Comment: Deleting isn't necessary, and the comment that that user posted was auto-generated by the site btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each class allows you to override `__str__` method you would do something like this

```py
class Initial:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5):
        ...

    def __str__(self):
        print(f"definition={self.definition}, {self.other}")
```